# NOT NULL constrain failed when trying to POST data to Django API

Tags: python, django

I have a project with two apps; a React app for the front-end and Django for backend.

I built my signup page in React and the signup process in Django. I would like to connect the two enabling a user to go through the signup page I created and for a user to be created based on the information submitted by the user.

Here is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    signup_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Serializers.py:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user_id', 'name', 'location', 'password', 'email', 'signup_confirmation')
```

and the POST function in React

```
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
        email: email,
        name: name,
        location: 'Example',
        password: password,
        user_id: 1,
    };
    console.log(user);
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.key) {
                localStorage.clear();
                localStorage.setItem('token',data.key);
                window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile/');
            } else {
                setEmail('');
                setName('');
                setPassword('');
                localStorage.clear();
                setErrors(true);
            }
        });
};
```

Problem is when I try to create a user; I get this error message in Django

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id
```

and when I check my network inspector I get a `Status code 500: Internal Server Error` message. Which upon further inspection (going to preview); I see this

```
IntegrityError at /api/v1/users/profiles/
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id
```

I also checked what I would get if I were to console log `res.text` inside my fetch() and this is what I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    

      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
      

      <title>Profile List – Django REST framework</title>

...
```

Any ideas regarding where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the title more closely.  It's not saying that you're violating a unique constraint, it's saying that the value you're passing in is null.

I'd change your OnetoOne to a ForeignKey relationship first.

Next, you need to actually create the user first and then you can assign a profile to the user.

I would also remove the email and password fields and rely on the [built in User model and functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/) to create your users.

Comment: Thanks, when tried this out ie. printing out User.objects.all(), I got this output:

<QuerySet [<User: EmmanuelSibs21>]>

Comment: OK, you can see what ID you have used by doing: `u.id`.  If it shows up as '1', you'll want to try a different ID with your user addition code.  Alternately, you can delete it with:  `u.delete()` I if I remember correctly.

Comment: I get the error no attribute 'id'

Comment: Ah, sorry:  `u[0].id` is what you want since it's a list.

Comment: Yeah, I get 1. So I tried changing user_id to 200, but still get the same error

Comment: Out of curiosity did the user get created?  You can use the code above to see if you have two users now.  Betting it didn't but just curious.

Comment: No new user created